# What dictates the order of group listing with id and groups command

Tags: ldap, coreutils, sssd

I am trying to work out what order the groups are listed by `id` and `groups` command (coreutils v8.22)

I am using LDAP and have configured SSSD to read user and group information.

My ldap server always returns the groups in this order for my account (ldapserach memberuid=myusername):

```
$ ldapsearch -b ou=groups,dc=domain,dc=com '(memberUid=myusername)' cn |grep ^cn: |cut -d: -f2 |tr '\n' ' '
people  admins  prodemo  dev  logadmins  video  netadmins
```

the `groups` command returns the groups like such:

```
$ groups
admins video prodemo people dev logadmins netadmins
```

if I use `groups myusername` the group listing is in this order:

```
$ groups myusername
myusername : admins netadmins logadmins video people dev prodemo
```

My primary group is 'admins' so that makes sense why that is the first group returned. I want to know what is going on here with the order of the rest and why would there be a difference in the order they are listed when I specify my username vs the bare `groups` command?

I have omitted `id` but it displays the same order.